# pandas groupby and sum for special case

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have below special case:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': ['A', 'A', 'E' ,'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'y': ['m', 'n', 'q', 'm', 'n', 'm', 'n'],
    'z':  [6,   5,  10,   4,   3,    2,   1]
})
print(df)
```

I need groupby x, then sum m and n of the value z. but drop all not m and values.

So the output should be:

```
:    x  sum
: 0  A  11
: 1  B  7
: 2  C  3
```

How can I use groupby to get the results? or other better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter your `df` to remove `y` values which are not `m` or `n`, then groupby using [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to assign a `sum` column:

```
out = (df[df['y'].isin(['m','n'])]
    .groupby('x', as_index=False)
    .agg(sum=('z', 'sum'))
)
```

Output:

```
   x  sum
0  A   11
1  B    7
2  C    3
```